# $http.get method in angularjs for rest Api

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

I want to fetch the list of friends for the REST-API into table using $http.get method in angularjs. Please see the  [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/nJuqo0jtg6Rtt0WNMNhk?p=preview). 
I am not able to load the JSON data, When I click on button.

JSON.data

```
{
    "friends": [
        {
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "Ann",
            "LastName": "Wellington"
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "Sabrina",
            "LastName": "Burke"
        }
    ]
}
```

Index.html

```
   <body ng-app="step4App">
        <div ng-controller="FriendsCtrl">
             <button ng-click="loadFriends()">Load Friends</button>
             <table>
                  <thead>
                     <tr><th>First</th><th>Last</th></tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends">
                          <td>{{friend.FirstName}}</td>
                          <td>{{friend.LastName}}</td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
             </table>

        </div>
        <script>
             var app=angular.module("step4App",[]);
             app.controller("FriendsCtrl", function($scope, $http){
                 $scope.loadFriends=function(){
                     $http.get("friendsList.json").success(function(data){
                          $scope.friends=data;
                     }).error(function(){
                          alert("An unexpected error occured!");
                     });
                 }
             });
        </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: Are you serving this from Apache? Or the local file system? If you're using Chrome, the local file system probably won't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON file have an object, and `$scope.friends` is an array.

You need change this:

```
$scope.friends=data;
```

to:

```
$scope.friends = data.friends;
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/meJWNMxgGp5V7minmUlr?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its working, I always confused  when this type situation arrive, could you explain more on this .......

Comment: What do you mean by "more"?